# How do I create a "select" button for a web app?

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, web-applications

this is my first foray into web apps and I only have fleeting training in HTML/CSS, so I apologize if this is all super basic.

I am making a web app for teachers to award points to a team using Google App Script. The web app will have three buttons with the name of the teams and a button for recording. When complete, I want the teacher to be able to select a team, click submit, and the entry is recorded on a Google Sheet. I understand the .gs (Google App Script) side of things, so I don't need help getting the data to the spreadsheet. I don't, though, entirely know how to handle the UI side of things.

My code is below. the record() function will send the team name to the App Script code. What I need help with are the buttons. I want to make it so the top three buttons (the teams) change color when clicked and only one can be clicked at a time (like a radial choice). So if I push "Team 1" then change to "Team 2", Team 1 will be unselected. Then, the score is only recorded when I press submit. I assume I will need to create a var that switches when the buttons are pushed, but how do I do that with CSS?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .button {
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            width: 300px;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }

        .button1 {
            background-color: green
        }

        .button2 {
            background-color: blue
        }

        .button3 {
            background-color: black
        }

        .button4 {
            background-color: red;
            margin-top: 20px;
            border-radius: 0px;
            width: 200px;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Which Team Earned a Point?</h1>
    <button class="button button1" id="char">Team1</button>
    <button class="button button2" id ="com">Team2</button>
    <button class="button button3" id="inq">Team3</button>

    <button class="button button4" id="sub" onclick="record()">Submit!</button>

    <script>
        function record(){
      google.script.run.pointUpdate();
    }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

TIA

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to achieve the desired result using CSS only by styling multiple `input type=radio` as buttons.
Here an example, in this code I am using a CSS rule to hide the input radio element.

```css
.radio-group .button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 16rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.radio-group .button-label {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    border: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: gray;
}

/* hide radio */
input[type="radio"] {
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

/* checked radio */
input[type="radio"]:checked  ~ .button-label {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-group">
    <label class="button">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-1">
        <div class="button-label">button 1</div>
    </label>
    <label class="button">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-1">
        <div class="button-label">button 2</div>
    </label>
    <label class="button">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-1">
        <div class="button-label">button 3</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution for the `HTML` side:

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <h1>Which Team Earned a Point?</h1>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="team1"
     name="team" value="team1value">
        <label for="team1">Team1</label>

        <input type="radio" id="team2"
     name="team" value="team2value">
        <label for="team2">Team2</label>

        <input type="radio" id="team3"
     name="team" value="team3value">
        <label for="team3">Team3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" onclick="record()">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        function record(){
      google.script.run.pointUpdate();
    }
    </script>

</body>
```

And this is how it will look on the UI of the web app:

**UI**

[image: web app ui]

**Explanation**

Since you want to make a choice between multiple elements, the best choice in this situation is to make use of radio buttons.

**Reference**

- [HTML Radio Button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).